# Mendix Error Handling for Custom Error

Tags: error-handling, mendix

I am doing a Mendix training right now. And I have been bugged by a question in the knowledge check for Error Handling part. The question is below

> What happens if the same microflows are used, but the error handling on the main microflow is Custom with Rollback and the error handling on the sub-microflow is Custom without Rollback?

And the correct answer is:

> The Order, OrderLine, and Log objects are rolled back while the Customer object is committed to the database

The Microflow on questions is :

[image]

My understanding is:

When the error in the mainmicroflow happens the Create Order should be rolledback but the Change in Customer should be committed since the main microflow uses `Custom with Rollback` and in the sub microflow both Orderline and the Log should be committed since the submicroflow uses `Custom without Rollback`.

Question:

Why is the correct answer `The Order, OrderLine, and Log objects are rolled back while the Customer object is committed to the database`

Below is Image as proof:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note I used to work for Mendix on their microflow engine (among others) 3 years ago but many things have changed. It seems you're using a concept  that is new to me which is the error event (where you exit your submicroflow) which according to the documentation at https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/error-event rethrows the error caught earlier.

I'm guessing that's why this is happening and would expect the order/orderline/log to be committed if you would exit that submicroflow with a normal end event after handling the error.